# Prove ${AG\over GE}={(m+1)(n+1)\over mn}$

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram. Two points $E$ and $F$ are chosen on the sides $BC$ and $CD$ respectively such that $\frac{EB}{EC}=m$ and $\frac{FC}{FD}=n$. Lines $AE$ and $BF$ intersect each other at $G$.

Prove that ratio ${AG\over GE}={(m+1)(n+1)\over mn}$

Comment: The ratios $m,n$ are somehow misleading. I think the problem would have a better statement if you said: for any points $E,F$ we would have: $$\frac{AG}{GE}=\frac{BC\;CD}{BE\;DF}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend $BF$, so it intersects $AD$ at $J$. Now obviously $\triangle AGJ \sim \triangle BGE$, so therefore $\frac{AG}{GE} = \frac{AJ}{BE}$. Now as $\triangle DFJ \sim \triangle ABJ$ we have that $\frac{AD}{AJ} = 1 - \frac{DJ}{AJ} = 1 -\frac{DF}{AB} = 1 - \frac{DF}{CD} = \frac{FC}{CD}$. So therefore:

$$\frac{AG}{GE} = \frac{AJ}{BE} = \frac{AJ}{AD} \cdot \frac{BC}{BE} = \frac{CD}{FC} \cdot \frac{BC}{BE}$$

which in fact is $\frac{(n+1)(m+1)}{mn}$